# Display specific coinmarketcap coin with API while using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api, get

I am trying to read some data about a specific coin of the Coinmarketcap API by using javascript, but nothing is happening. I really don't know where it's going  wrong...

```js
    var coin = "spectrecoin";

    $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/spectrecoin/", function(data, status) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      if (data[i].id == "spectrecoin") {
        $("#rank").html(data[i].rank);
        $("#price").html(data[i].price_usd);
      }
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Coin Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="rank"></td>
        <td id="price"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never entering the `for` loop. Change

```
i < data.length - 1
```

to

```
i < data.length
```